# Password cannot be accepted or input in non-graphical mode

Tags: 16.04, login, pam

I use `Ctrl + Alt + F1` to switch to non-graphical mode. I **only** input my username called *bryan* and click `Enter`. The screen automatically shows that:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS bryan-5810 tty1

bryan-5810 login: bryan
password:

login incorrect
bryan-5810 login:

login incorrect
bryan-5810 login:

login incorrect
bryan-5810 login:
```

At the same time, the system log (auth.log) shows

```
Mar 26 20:36:59 bryan-5810 login[5709]: pam_unix(login:auth): conversation failed
Mar 26 20:36:59 bryan-5810 login[5709]: pam_unix(login:auth): auth could not identify password for [bryan]
Mar 26 20:37:02 bryan-5810 login[5709]: FAILED LOGIN (1) on '/dev/tty1' FOR 'bryan', Authentication failure
Mar 26 20:37:02 bryan-5810 login[5709]: pam_securetty(login:auth): cannot determine username
Mar 26 20:37:05 bryan-5810 login[5709]: FAILED LOGIN (2) on '/dev/tty1' FOR 'UNKNOWN', Error in service module
Mar 26 20:37:05 bryan-5810 login[5709]: pam_securetty(login:auth): cannot determine username
Mar 26 20:37:09 bryan-5810 login[5709]: FAILED LOGIN (3) on '/dev/tty1' FOR 'UNKNOWN', Error in service module
Mar 26 20:37:09 bryan-5810 login[5709]: pam_securetty(login:auth): cannot determine username
Mar 26 20:37:12 bryan-5810 login[5709]: FAILED LOGIN (4) on '/dev/tty1' FOR 'UNKNOWN', Error in service module
Mar 26 20:37:12 bryan-5810 login[5709]: pam_securetty(login:auth): cannot determine username
Mar 26 20:37:16 bryan-5810 login[5709]: FAILED LOGIN (5) on '/dev/tty1' FOR 'UNKNOWN', Error in service module
Mar 26 20:37:16 bryan-5810 login[5709]: TOO MANY LOGIN TRIES (5) on '/dev/tty1' FOR 'UNKNOWN'
Mar 26 20:37:16 bryan-5810 login[5709]: pam_mail(login:session): cannot determine username
Mar 26 20:37:16 bryan-5810 login[5709]: pam_unix(login:session): close_session - error recovering username
```

Could you please give me some advices? I do not know how to fix the problems. From the log files, I think there are problems about `pam`. Thank you for any replies.

Comment: Simple steps first --- Make sure that your Caps Lock is not on

Comment: Do you write the right password at the `password:` prompt ? There will be no output when you type. If your password has special characters, the keyboard layout may be wrong. You can try to write the password at the `login:` to see what characters that is entered, and delete it again with backspace's.

Comment: Probably a bad keyboard. Do you have another to try?

Comment: My password is simple enough, which is `hello` with lowercase letters. There is nothing about the keyboard, I think. Because Ubuntu does not allow me to input my password after I input my username and click `enter`.

Comment: @BryanYU Has nothing to do with the simplicity of your password. It has to do with the keyboard generating spurious characters on its own. Try another keyboard...

Comment: @heynnema I use TeamViewer to log in to the ubuntu in another PC (a Thinkpad laptop) and manipulate it remotely. Sadly, it shows the same result.

Comment: @BryanYU So are you saying that this symptom occurs on BOTH the local computer's keyboard, AND via TV? If so, then you should add that detail to your question.

Comment: @heynnema Yes, it still does not allow me to input a password.

Comment: @BryanYU But via GUI it works fine? Log in via GUI, open `terminal`, type `who`.

Comment: @heynnema `who : 
bryan    tty7         2020-03-26 21:27 (:0)`. Everything in GUI terminal seems normal.

Comment: Does it jump straight from asking for username to login incorrect?

Comment: @BryanYU Try three more things... `ls -al /etc/securetty` and `grep -i tty1 /etc/securetty` and `grep -i bryan /etc/passwd`.

Comment: @heynnema`➜  ~ ls -al /etc/securetty        -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4038 3月  29  2016 /etc/securetty
➜  ~ grep -i bryan /etc/passwd
bryan:x:1000:1000:bryan,,,:/home/bryan:/bin/zsh`

Comment: @BryanYU You forgot the 2nd command

Comment: @heynnema `➜  ~ grep -i tty1 /etc/securetty
tty1
tty10
tty11
tty12
tty13
tty14
tty15
tty16
tty17
tty18
tty19
3270/tty1
lxc/tty1`

Comment: @BryanYU still scratching my head...

Comment: @heynnema I think it is related to *Linux PAM* but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: @BryanYU that's what I was beginning to check. type `man securetty` for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem but I still feel confused. I follow [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64545/suddenly-i-cant-login-with-correct-password-greeter-tty). However I adopt parts of them:
1. creating directory: `/var/lib/samba` and adding myself to samba passwords database (`sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/samba && sudo smbpasswd -a myusername`.
2. `sudo pam-auth-update` (all the authentication modules were already selected, so I just cliked okay using `blankspace`).
3. reboot